# Boost Beast async HTTP client + std::future

Tags: c++, promise, boost-asio, future, boost-beast

I have a project that will do some networking and would like to wrap underlying Boost Beast HTTP(S) requests implementation inside futures.

I copied the `session` class from https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/beast/example/http/client/async-ssl/http_client_async_ssl.cpp and want to change `session::run()` return type to `std::future<http::response<http::string_body>>`. Also, change the place `// Write the message to standard out` to setting up the result in the promise instead of printing.

The questions are:

- where to put the promise that will be used to generate the future? Is the class member a right choice?
- where to put `boost::asio::io_context ioc`? Should it be in the core loop of my own application (assuming the application will fire multiple requests during it's lifetime) and then pass a reference to `ioc` when making requests? **What about the `ioc.run()`? - I need it to run constantly, should I open a dedicated thread for running `ioc` to avoid blocking?**
- How to handle `session` errors? I would like to use `std::promise` interface and put there an exception in case something goes wrong - basically replace all calls to `fail()` in the example with appropriate exceptions. But I can't just put an exception object into the promise, it expects `std::exception_ptr` - should I just throw, instantly catch it and put `std::current_exception()`? This seems like a bad hack to me.
- Will this work if I don't explicitly create any threads in the program? If no, what would be a good way to query the `session` object that all tasks are complete?

Edit: added further question about `ioc` (in bold)

Comment: "But I can't just put an exception object into the promise, it expects std::exception_ptr" Have you tried `std::make_exception_ptr`?
Otherwise, everything you mentioned seems fine

Comment: @KABoissonneault ahh, so there is a standard library wrapper for it. Good.